# mruby: How to execute shell commands?

Tags: ruby, mruby

In mruby how can I run shell commands with `%x()`, ``` `` ``` or `system`?
Is there an mgem I can use for it?

Comment: Valid question - hopefully mruby can include the answer once that is resolved.

Comment: once what is resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `mruby-io` which implementes `popen`:
https://github.com/iij/mruby-io/blob/728d313b2c238ac0f41a4aa7e4a88e6a8fee8079/mrblib/kernel.rb#L2-L4

Or type `mruby-process` which implements `system`: https://github.com/iij/mruby-process/blob/c31010dc0440335a7693fd70ae005c79bd1378ec/src/process.c#L368

Comment: I found the `system` in mruby-process but it doesn't return anything from the process.
I actually implemented a version of the backtick operator, and got a simple version working but it makes a lot more sense to use mruby-io instead.